# Replace Null value with string in ssrs expression

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-grouping

I have a row  group of STATUS fields. There is a group that returns null that I would like to change to chat. I have tried:

```
=Iif(IsNothing(Fields!STATUS.Value), "Chat", Fields!STATUS.Value)
```

but the group still returns blank. Would anyone have any ideas on how to help me resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is right. Are you sure it's returning nothing, and not something like a space or carriage return?

Comment: I am not sure. How would i check that?

Comment: I ran the grouping through SSMS to see if what it reported out as. And it is `NULL`

Comment: Something must have been cached weird, because now this seems to be working for me...

Comment: @scapegoat17. Well, glad it's working for you at least. For future reference you can use something like Replace(Fields!STATUS.Value, vbcrlf, "XXX") to make the cell display XXX if it encounters a carriage return (vbcrlf is carriage return in Visual Basic). Other common things to look for are Chr(10) and Chr(13) which also have this affect sometimes.